# Strange behavior in table view after deleting event

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, tableview, swift4

I am working on an app which has users register for volunteering events, and am currently working on letting them view their own events and unregister.

[image]

This is the screen the users sees when the ask to view their events, in this case the two events are called "ok" and "that" (I just created some random testing events). When you click on one this is the screen you get:

[image]

When you click unregister, the event is deleted from your registeredEvents, but the table view now has two of the same events.

[image]

When I click back, and then go back to the table view, everything is normal, in this case only displaying the "ok" event, because the other one was deleted. Here is the code for the tableview layout:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    yourArray = []
    actualEvents = []
    let id = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(id!).child("registeredEvents").observe(.value) { snapshot in
          let children = snapshot.children
             while let rest = children.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot, let value = rest.value {
                print(value)
                  self.yourArray.append(value as! String)
              }
               Database.database().reference().child("Events").observe(.value) { (data) in
                    let events = data.value as! [String:[String:Any]]
                    for(_,value) in events{
                        if(self.yourArray.contains(value["EventName"]! as! String)){
                            self.actualEvents.append(PersonalEvents(evName: value["EventName"]! as! String, evDesc: value["EventDescription"]! as! String, evStartDate: value["start time"]! as! String, evEndDate: value["end time"] as! String, evNumPeople: value["NumberOfPeople"]! as! Int, evNumRegistered: value["currentPeople"] as! Int))
                           }
                        }
                        print("Actual events array " + "\(self.actualEvents)")
                  }
            self.tblEvents.reloadData()
        }
        print(yourArray)
        self.tblEvents.dataSource = self
        self.tblEvents.delegate = self
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return yourArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "productstable", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.yourArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

And the unregister button(This is in a different view controller, becuase info is displayed about the events in a different view):

```
 @IBAction func didUnregister(_ sender: Any) {
    let id = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("users").child(id!).child("registeredEvents").child(personalEventInfo!.eventName!).removeValue { error,arg  in
      if error != nil {
          print("error \(error)")
      }
    }
    let event = ref.child("Events")
    event.child(personalEventInfo!.eventName!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
        var currentPeople = value["currentPeople"] as! Int
        currentPeople = currentPeople - 1
    Database.database().reference().child("Events").child(self.personalEventInfo!.eventName!).child("currentPeople").setValue(currentPeople)
    }
}
```

Please let me know if this is confusing, but if it is not, then please let me know why this is happening, and what I can do to fix it.

Comment: It's kind of confusing but try calling `tblEvents.reloadData()` after unregistering an event and see if that helps. Also you don't need to use `self` everywhere. Try reading a short blog post about it. e.g. `self.tblEvents.dataSource` you don't need to use `self`  there. When you update your datasource such as adding our deleting an object for your `tableview` mostly you also need to inform your `tableView` to update its view (cells).

Comment: sorry i should have mentioned that the unregister is in a different class, meaning I cant do tblEvents.reloadData()

Answer (score 1):

- Remove the items inside the Array before you append the data inside.
- Improvement: You need to take care your memory by using [weak self] inside these closures.

Can you try the following:

```
 Database.database().reference().child("users").child(id!).child("registeredEvents").observe(.value) { [weak self] snapshot in

    let children = snapshot.children
    self?.yourArray.removeAll()
         while let rest = children.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot, let value = rest.value {
            print(value)
              self?.yourArray.append(value as! String)
          }

    Database.database().reference().child("Events").observe(.value) { [weak self] (data) in
                let events = data.value as! [String:[String:Any]]

                self?.actualEvents.removeAll()
                for(_,value) in events{
                    if(self?.yourArray.contains(value["EventName"]! as! String)){
                        self?.actualEvents.append(PersonalEvents(evName: value["EventName"]! as! String, evDesc: value["EventDescription"]! as! String, evStartDate: value["start time"]! as! String, evEndDate: value["end time"] as! String, evNumPeople: value["NumberOfPeople"]! as! Int, evNumRegistered: value["currentPeople"] as! Int))
                       }
                    }
                    print("Actual events array " + "\(self?.actualEvents)")
              }
        self?.tblEvents.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: i tried what you said, and for some reason, it will ocassionally throw an error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) on the line                     "if(self?.yourArray.contains(value["EventName"]! as! String)){". This happens when I click unregister or register, but only happens once in a while. Do you know what caused this?

Comment: Ok I figured it out, I simply used my previous code, using [weak self] like you suggested, and adding self?.yourArray.removeAll(), right after the first observe closure